# Get to know domain and context root url path in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angularJS application is running in a web server with the following path

```
http://www.some.domain.com/some/path/
```

Notice that `/some/path/` is dynamic path because my app can be deployed to any web server to any directory. I need to get this absolute URL in AngularJS excluding all inner angular pages. For instance, if current user's page is

```
http://www.some.domain.com/some/path/inner/angular/page.html
```

then the code that I am looking for should return

```
http://www.some.domain.com/some/path/
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location.  Specifically, `$location.host()` should return what you want.

Comment: Are you using Angulars own routing? You might want to check here, see if any of that would help you: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: A couple of methods I have used: when using a build system for my client-side app (almost always) *AND* the context root is known at build time, I set an Angular constant through the build system (e.g. [grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant)/[gulp-ng-constant](https://github.com/guzart/gulp-ng-constant)). Sometimes I make the main HTML page dynamic (JSP in my case) and set a global JS var with a scriptlet: `var contextPath = '<%= request.getContextPath() %>';`. Otherwise (but least preferably) URL sniffing - e.g. through `$location`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos yeah I supply context root as a grunt parameter, so I know the context root in advance. However, I thought there is an easier way to get context root AND domain, port of the web server my app is running on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$location` because it only has information about the current SPA.

The code that you are looking for (`"/some/path/"`) is this:

```
var myContextWithPath = $window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Other variation that returns only the context (`"/some"`) is this:

```
var myContext = $window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));
```

You can also obtain the origin (`"http://www.some.domain.com"`):

```
var origin = $window.location.origin;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$location` for this. **Don't forget the add $location in to controller function**

```
$location.host()
```

gives you base url.Which is application base server domain, like : www.example.com

```
$location.port()
```

gives you port like : 8080

```
$location.path()
```

gives you where you are : index.html

Comment: Yeah, I know this, I thought there must be some handy utility for doing it. But thanks anyway.